# button onclick listner on ListView using SimpleAdapter not working

Tags: android, android-listview, buttonclick

I want to make click listner on button on listview ..i made listview using SimpleAdapter as given code...

[image]

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        UserBookmarks.this, bookmarksList,
                        R.layout.list_view_boookmarks, new String[] { BOOKMARK_NAME , BOOKMARK_CATEGORY , BOOKMARKS_RATTING_BAR, BOOKMARKS_REVIEW_TOTAL , BOOKMARKS_CITY }, new int[] { R.id.business_name , R.id.business_category , R.id.ratting, R.id.review_count,R.id.business_city });


adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation)
    {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.removeBookmark) 
        {
              Button b=(Button) view;
              b.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     Log.d("HIiiiiiiiiiii", "Button clickeddddddddd");
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click listner called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             });
             return true; 
         }
        return false;
    }
 });
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

but onclick listner not working on this code....i have tried too much but could not solve this ....if anyoone get plz answer...
and how to know on which button id user clicked..means list position...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the following code

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(UserBookmarks.this, bookmarksList,
  R.layout.list_view_boookmarks, new String[] { BOOKMARK_NAME , BOOKMARK_CATEGORY ,         BOOKMARKS_RATTING_BAR, BOOKMARKS_REVIEW_TOTAL , BOOKMARKS_CITY ,**BUTTONLABEL**}, new int[] { R.id.business_name , R.id.business_category , R.id.ratting, R.id.review_count,R.id.business_city ,**R.id.removeBookmark**});
```

add the bold field in your code 
[Click here for code Help](http://www.androidsourcehelp.com/2014/03/simple-listview-with-viewbinder-android.html)

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is arising because of this id "removeBookmark".

Comment: Why did you use R.id.removeBookmark in your view binder? Because you didn't pass this id into your adapter.

Comment: removeBookmark is id of cross button,so i think don't need to pass in adapter...it's static..

if you have other ideas to implement this logic plz give me......

Comment: Than you have to use custom adapter and write this OnClickListener into that custom adapter.